# Substitute onclick with addEventListener

Tags: javascript

In a for loop I found this legacy code and I want to use `addEventListener("click"...)` instead of the current `onclick`. How can I convert this piece of code? I can't undestand how can I pass the function as the second argument of the `addEventListener` method.

```
el.onclick = (function() {
                  var value="num"+i;
                  //
                  return function() {test(value);}
})();
```

Comment: `el.addEventLister('click', foo)`

Comment: How do I pass "num"+i in foo?

Comment: pass in an anonymous function

Answer (score 0):

You put everything on the right hand side of the `=` (except, obviously, the `;` at the end) in the spot for the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
el.addEventListener("click", function(i) {
    var value="num"+i;          
    return function() {
        test(value);
    };
}(i), false);
```

Comment: But: how can I remove the listener then?

Comment: @user1440263 do you need to remove it? you could simply remove the element. Removing the listener alone is not that simple because if this is in a loop, you need an array to  store all the handler references etc.. but basically you can call `removeEventListener( "click", functionRef, false)` if you have the `functionRef` (which you don't, in this case)

Comment: I come from languages where you remove listeners when they're not used anymore, I never heard of totally removing an element, but if this is fine in JS, I'll do it

Comment: @user1440263 I mean if you are gonna remove the element anyway, you don't have to remove the listeners as well. If you need to just remove the listener, then you need to store all the function references somewhere. But again, if you are just gonna remove the element anyway, then just remove the element.

Answer (score 0):

```
el.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
    var value = "num" + i;
    test( value );
}, false );

// If you want named functions
el.addEventListener( 'click', someName, false );
function someName() {
    var value = "num" + i;
    test( value );
}
```

The legacy code puts `value` in the closure of where `test(value)` is executed, but the code up there does the same.

Also, your legacy piece of code wraps the `onclick` handler in a self executing function, so the *actual* event handler is what is returned. Thus why, the code I just wrote is the same.

Comment: `i` suggests that this code is inside a loop, so this won't work (if it's inside a loop)?

Comment: Is there any way to convert the anonymous function to a regular function with a name, preserving its current behavior?

Comment: @user1440263 yes, give it a name.

Comment: @Esailija I'd add a closure for the loop then, but having a self executing function and returning a new function doesn't make sense, and isn't required.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: it seems for the person who wrote the code it made sense because without it, it doesn't work at all

Comment: @user1440263 I added a named function example :)

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: so in the scope of someName "num"+i is perfectly legal

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: the example with the named function doesn't work in my context